# How is a Cookie validated internally by ASP.NET MVC using CookieAuthenticationMiddleware

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, owin

I'm trying to figure out how ASP.NET internally validates that a cookie will allow the user to access the application.

CookieAuthenticationMiddleware will set .AspNet.Cookies with an encrypted value. After .NET successfully decrypts the cookie on a request, what validation occurs then?

Developing locally with IISExpress if I have an application (#1) that sets an authentication Cookie after the user logs in, and I create a complete new application (#2) also running on localhost, that is also using CookieAuthentication. When I access #2 it will read the cookie from #1 and allows the user to access the application as well.

I'm trying to understand what the limits are for cookie authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really any "validation" per se. The cookie's encrypted key is used to reference the user that should be "logged in". It works in a very similar way to sessions, where the session cookie holds an encrypted session id that the server can use to look up and restore the session via.

The encryption/decryption is based on the machine key, which either may be explicitly set in the Web.config or generated automatically by ASP.NET. Only applications that share the same machine key may decrypt the cookie, which is why it's so important to protect your machine key.

Anyways, there's two factors involved here. First, cookies are domain bound: only the domain or subdomains of the domain the cookie is set on will be given the cookie. This is handled by the client (i.e. browser). Your two applications currently are able to both see the cookie because they're both running on localhost. However, if you were to deploy one at foo.com and the other at bar.com, then they would no longer be able to see each other's cookies.

Second, the machine key is typically by server (unless you explicitly set it in the Web.config per app). As a result, sites running on the same machine can usually decrypt each other's cookies (assuming they see them in the first place, which again, is based on their domain).

It's not clear whether you're happy or not about this arrangement. If your goal is to segregate the two sites running locally, such that they don't share cookies, you have a couple of options.

1. You can explicitly set a *different* machine key for each site in their respective Web.config files. They'll still receive any cookies set by the other site, but they'll no longer be able to decrypt them, which basically results in them being ignored.
2. You can customize the auth cookie name. Instead of using the default cookie name you can make one `.Site1.Auth` and the other `.Site2.Auth`. Then, even though either site will also receive the cookie for the other site, it will simply ignore it, because it's not the auth cookie for it.

If, however, you're intending to rely on this behavior in production as well (i.e. you actually *want* logging into one site to log you into the other as well), then you'll need to explicitly set the machine key to the *same* value in both site's Web.config files. Additionally, you'll need to deploy them on the same domain, or at least subdomains of that domain. In the case of subdomains, you'll need to set the cookie domain to be the wildcard domain `.mydomain.com` for both. Then, you could have one at `foo.mydomain.com` and another at `bar.mydomain.com`, and they'd both see the cookie because it was set on `.mydomain.com`. If you leave it the default, set on the actual domain of the site, then `bar.mydomain.com` could not see a cookie set by `foo.mydomain.com` because that cookie would be explicitly set only for `foo.mydomain.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer.

Answer (score 1):

The primary validations are encryption and expiration. If apps share an encryption context (e.g. machine key) then they can share auth cookies (providing other client side sharing rules like domains and paths are satisfied). So yes it's expected that two apps using IIS Express localhost on the same machine would share cookies by default.

The expiration is also embedded in the encrypted value so the client can't tamper with it.